# Trying to understand numerical solutions using the iteration method

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I am given the equation of a curve
$$ y = x\ln(8-x)$$
The slope of the curve is said to be 1 at only one point, $x = a$.
There are three parts to this question.

**- Show that $a$ satisfies the equation $$x = 8- \frac{8}{\ln(8-x)}$$**

The way I did this part is by finding the derivative of y (which is $-\frac{x}{8-x} + \ln(8-x)$ and equating it to 1, and solving for x. I get $$x = 8 - e^\frac{8}{8-a}$$ How do I get it into the form $x = 8- \frac{8}{\ln(8-x)}$? I suspect there is some exponent manipulation I can't think of.

**- Verify by calculation $a$ lies between 2.9 and 3.1**
Now I substituted 2.9 and 3.1 into y, but I did not get a sign-change. It seems to me as if *I'm not looking for a sign-change here... I'm looking for some other characteristic. Can someone detail what I'm looking for, and why -- intuitively, so I can do this on any other problem I get like this?*

Also, we are not looking for the x-intercept(s) of $y$, we are looking for where it cuts the point $x = a$, right? *How does that change things?* I think it means that I will have to use $x = y$?

I think I'll be able to do the third part myself, but I believe there are some conceptual gaps I need to fill first.

Comment: $\ln(8-x) = \ln{\left(e^{\frac 8 {8-a} }\right)}=\frac 8 {8-a}$

Comment: Since at $x=a$, $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = 1$, Now suppose, $g(x)=y-x$ then at $x=a$, $\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}x} = 0$.Now try to find sign change in  $\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}x} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, you don't need to switch to exponential form.

$$\begin{align}
-\frac{x}{8-x} + \ln (8-x) &= 1\\
\\
\ln (8-x) &= 1 + \frac{x}{8-x} \\
\\
 \ln (8-x) &= \frac{8-x}{8-x} + \frac{x}{8-x} \\
\\
\ln (8-x) &= \frac{8}{8-x} \\
\\
8-x &= \frac{8}{\ln (8-x)} \\
\\
x &= 8 - \frac{8}{\ln (8-x)}
\end{align}$$

For the second part, remember that $a$ is a solution to the above equation, not the original function. Just re-write the above equation as

$$x - 8 + \frac{8}{\ln (8-x)} = 0$$

Now evaluate at $x=2.9$ and $x=3.1$:

$$\begin{align}
2.9 - 8 + \frac{8}{\ln (8-2.9)} \approx -0.19 \\
3.1 - 8 + \frac{8}{\ln (8-3.1)} \approx 0.13
\end{align}$$

The sign change indicates $a$ must lie between $2.9$ and $3.1$.